# How to save sizes of resizable element (JQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, resize

There are a few questions on this subject already, however none of them solve my problem.

I have blocks on my page that can be resized inside parent container. I want them to save last size they were stretched to, so when user refresh page it looked the same.

This is what I tried to do:

```
$( ".resizable_content" ).resizable({
handles: "se",
stop: function(evet, ui) {
    let resElem = document.getElementById(this.id);
    var w = ui.size.width;
    var h = ui.size.height;
    console.log(w, h);
    resElem.style.height = h;
    resElem.style.width = w;
}});
```

I'm getting the sizes of streched element and apply it to css styles. However, after page refresh it returs to initial state.

And to mention, each of these blocks contains an iframe element that stretches to 100% of the parent.

UPD:
About local storage.
I have a code:

```
var sHeight = localStorage.height || "{}",
sWidth = localStorage.width || "{}",
height = JSON.parse(sHeight),
width = JSON.parse(sWidth);
$.each(height, function (id, height) {
   $("#" + id).css(height)
})
$.each(width, function (id, width) {
   $("#" + id).css(width)
 })
$(".resizable_content" ).resizable({
// containment: ".content",
handles: "se",
stop: function (event, ui) {
    height[this.id] = ui.size.height
    width[this.id] = ui.size.width
    localStorage.height = JSON.stringify(height)
    localStorage.width = JSON.stringify(width)
}});
```

But i keep getting a type error a.replace is not a function

UPDx2:
HTML (elements tooked from db and inserted in html page):

```
<!-- DB loaded frames -->
        <div class="frameDb__content">
            <?php $frames = get_frames();?>
            <!-- $i - incremented element for unique IDs of resizable elements -->
            <?php $i=0;?> 
            <!--  -->
            <?php foreach($frames as $frame): ?>
                <div class="resizable_content drag" id="resize_<?php echo $i;?>">
                    <iframe 
                        src="<?=$frame["url"]?>" 
                        id="<?=$frame["frameID"]?>" 
                        class="<?=$frame["frameID"]?>_frame mainframe ui-widget-content drop" 
                        scrolling="no" 
                        frameborder="0"
                        style="height:85%; width:85%;">Ваш браузер не поддерживает Фреймы</iframe>   
                </div>
                <?php $i++;?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
<!--end DB load -->
```

CSS:

```
/*initial size of added frame*/
.resizable_content {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
}
/*content-wrapper. Elements can't go beyond*/
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Save the sizes to localStorage in the `stop` handler, and read the values and apply them to the element in document.ready.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, I edit the question. With the code above I start getting an error: a.replace is not a function. Apparently the error is caused by $.each. Can you give a sample of working code

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include all relevant HTML/CSS/JS so that we can see a working example of the issue

Comment: Done. I can also attach a php file that handles the function get_frames(), but that doesn't seem needed